# How to execute Google Script bound to Google Form on Form open

Tags: forms

I am developing very first script for Google Forms. And of course I need help :)

Intro:
Script needs to collect external data (API), create drop down filled with fetched data and upon submission send all responses to another API.

So far I got:
1. Fetching external API - works;
2. Creating drop down filled with data - works partially;
3. Sending data - not yet started.

I have following specific questions:

1. For some reason data in drop down is not being refreshed (fetched) on form open. I have it in function onOpen() and created trigger to execute this function on open as well. However only way to get new data is to go to script editor and run it :( Which is not the point.
2. Drop down is currently at the bottom of the form. I saw that you can use index, but I can not get it working. Can someone give me working example of how to use https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#moveitemitem-toindex properly?

Thanks!